# How to appending a column db result with relation and some logic laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-4, query-builder

I have a problem here, I want to add one column from the result of the relation, namely the percentage column, this column is the result of pagebook / pageread * 100
this is my result db what I want

```
"id": 2,
    "id_book": 2,
    "id_user": 2,
    "pageread": 120,
    "books": {
                "id": 2,
                "pagebook":125
             }
    "percentage":96
```

this is my code in controller

```
$book= Read::with('books.authors')->where('id_user',$user->id)->get();
```

and this my code in model

```
public function books()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Book::class,'id_book','id');
    }
```

Comment: Look into resources: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-resources#introduction they allow you to include such info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it in the model:

```
class YourModel ...{
    protected $appends = ['percentage'];
    public function getPercentageAttribute()
    {
        return /* the calculation that you need */
    }
}
```

Comment: how can i send parameter book->pagebook and pageread to getPercentageAttribute for calculate?

Comment: @Newbie123 same way you would have done in a controller or anywhere else

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected $appends = ['percentage'];
    public function getPercentageAttribute()
    {
        $read= $this->pageread;
        $book= $this->books->pagebook
        return $read/$book*100


    }
```